dropdown list (ul – unordered list and li - list item element) is not working when added dynamically
I have drop down list that working fine when I add it as static object.
But when I add it dynamically from JavaScript its there but not working . not dropping down or toggle using this class="my-main-menu".
var LoginInfoDataSet;
$('#Modal4').modal('toggle');
MenuDataSet = response[0].MenuAllContent;
MenuHeaderDataSet = response[0].MenuHeaders;

var MenuAllContent = "";
var AllMenuContent = "";
var MenuHeaderTemplate = '<li class="my-main-menu"><a class="my-main-menu-1"><i style="font-size:18px; " class="fa fa-handshake"></i>' + MenuHeaderTitle + '<span class="arrow"></span></a> <div data-level="2"><ul >' + MenuHeaderContent + '</ul></div><hr class="Horizontal-Line1" /></li >';
var MenuHeaderTitle = "";
var MenuHeaderContent = "";
var LinkCode = "";
var LinkTitle = "";
var SubMenuTitle = "";
var SubMenuContent = "";
var DirectLinkTemplate = '<li> <a class="my-main-menu-1" onclick="GetAddPage(' + "'" + LinkCode + "'" + ')">  <i style="margin-top:6px; font-size:8px" class="fa fa-circle"></i>' + LinkTitle + '</a></li>';
var SubMenuTemplate = '<li class="submodule"> <a class="my-main-menu-1">  <i style="margin-top:6px; font-size:8px" class="fa fa-circle"></i> ' + SubMenuTitle + '<span class="arrow1"></span></a>  <div data-level="3"> <ul> ' + SubMenuContent + '</ul> </div > </li > ';
var SubLinkTemplate = ' <li class="submodule"> < a class="my-main-menu-1" onclick = "GetAddPage(' + "'" + LinkCode + "'" + ')" > <i style="margin-top:6px; font-size:8px" class="fa fa-circle"></i>' + LinkTitle + '</a > </li >'
var CompareTitle = "";
var i = 0;

do {
    CompareTitle = MenuHeaderDataSet[i].Col1

    var ii = 0;
    do {

        if (MenuDataSet[ii].Col1 == CompareTitle) {
            if (SubMenuTitle != "" && MenuDataSet[ii].Col4 != "3") {
                SubMenuTemplate = '<li class="submodule"> <a class="my-main-menu-1">  <i style="margin-top:6px; font-size:8px" class="fa fa-circle"></i> ' + SubMenuTitle + '<span class="arrow1"></span></a>  <div data-level="3"> <ul> ' + SubMenuContent + '</ul> </div > </li > ';

                // add the submenu to MenuContenet
                MenuHeaderContent += SubMenuTemplate;
                SubMenuTitle = "";
                SubMenuContent = "";
                alert(MenuHeaderContent)
            }

            switch (MenuDataSet[ii].Col4) {
                case "1":
                    LinkCode = MenuDataSet[ii].Col3;
                    LinkTitle = MenuDataSet[ii].Col2;
                    DirectLinkTemplate = '<li> <a class="my-main-menu-1" onclick="GetAddPage(' + "'" + LinkCode + "'" + ')">  <i style="margin-top:6px; font-size:8px" class="fa fa-circle"></i>' + LinkTitle + '</a></li>';

                    MenuHeaderContent += DirectLinkTemplate;

                    break;

                case "2":
                    SubMenuTitle = MenuDataSet[ii].Col2;
                    break;
                case "3":
                    LinkCode = MenuDataSet[ii].Col3;

                    LinkTitle = MenuDataSet[ii].Col2;

                    SubLinkTemplate = ' <li class="submodule"> < a class="my-main-menu-1" onclick = "GetAddPage(' + "'" + LinkCode + "'" + ')" > <i style="margin-top:6px; font-size:8px" class="fa fa-circle"></i>' + LinkTitle + '</a > </li >'

                    SubMenuContent += SubLinkTemplate;
                      alert(SubMenuContent)
                    break;

            }
        }

        ii++;
    }
    while (ii < MenuDataSet.length)

    if (SubMenuTitle != "") {
        SubMenuTemplate = '<li class="submodule"> <a class="my-main-menu-1">  <i style="margin-top:6px; font-size:8px" class="fa fa-circle"></i> ' + SubMenuTitle + '<span class="arrow1"></span></a>  <div data-level="3"> <ul> ' + SubMenuContent + '</ul> </div > </li > ';
        MenuHeaderContent += SubMenuTemplate;
        SubMenuTitle = "";
        SubMenuContent = "";

    }

    MenuHeaderTemplate = '<li class="my-main-menu"><a class="my-main-menu-1"><i style="font-size:18px" class="fa fa-handshake"></i>' + CompareTitle + '<span class="arrow"></span></a> <div data-level="2"><ul >' + MenuHeaderContent + '</ul></div><hr class="Horizontal-Line1" /></li >';

    AllMenuContent += MenuHeaderTemplate;
    i++;
}
while (i < MenuHeaderDataSet.length)
MenuAllContent = AllMenuContent;

document.getElementById("MainMenu").innerHTML = "";
try {
    // document.getElementById("MainMenu").innerHtml = MenuAllContent insertAdjacentElement  insertAdjacentHTML
    document.getElementById("MainMenu").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", MenuAllContent)

}
catch (ee) {
    alert(ee)
}

I tried to use innerHtml and insertAdjacentHTML but none of them working for me.
the issue is in the method how i add the dropdown list
I checked some of the existing articles and questions but I can not what is wrong.

This is example I came up with please add logic to how your menu should behave e.g. redirect to page...
also change menu dataset and menu header data set to your needs


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var MenuDataSet = [
    { Col1: 'Main', Col2: 'SubLink1', Col3: 'Code1', Col4: '3' },
    { Col1: 'Main', Col2: 'SubLink2', Col3: 'Code2', Col4: '3' },
    { Col1: 'Services', Col2: 'Inquiry', Col3: 'ServiceCode1', Col4: '1' },
    { Col1: 'Contact', Col2: 'Email Us', Col3: 'ContactCode1', Col4: '1' }
];

    var MenuHeaderDataSet = [
    { Col1: 'Main' },
    { Col1: 'Services' },
    { Col1: 'Contact' }
];
    var MenuAllContent = "";
    var AllMenuContent = "";
    
    for (var i = 0; i < MenuHeaderDataSet.length; i++) {
        var MenuHeaderContent = "";
        var CompareTitle = MenuHeaderDataSet[i].Col1;
        
        for (var ii = 0; ii < MenuDataSet.length; ii++) {
            if (MenuDataSet[ii].Col1 === CompareTitle) {
                switch (MenuDataSet[ii].Col4) {
                    case "1":
                        MenuHeaderContent += '<li><a class="my-main-menu-1" data-linkcode="' + MenuDataSet[ii].Col3 + '">' + MenuDataSet[ii].Col2 + '</a></li>';
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        MenuHeaderContent += '<li class="submodule"><a class="my-main-menu-1" data-linkcode="' + MenuDataSet[ii].Col3 + '">' + MenuDataSet[ii].Col2 + '</a></li>';
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        var MenuHeaderTemplate = '<li class="my-main-menu"><a class="my-main-menu-1">' + CompareTitle + '<span class="arrow"></span></a><div data-level="2"><ul>' + MenuHeaderContent + '</ul></div><hr class="Horizontal-Line1" /></li>';
        AllMenuContent += MenuHeaderTemplate;
    }
    
    MenuAllContent = AllMenuContent;
    document.getElementById("MainMenu").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", MenuAllContent);

    
    document.getElementById('MainMenu').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        if (e.target && e.target.nodeName == "A" && e.target.classList.contains('my-main-menu-1')) {
            var linkCode = e.target.dataset.linkcode;
            if (linkCode) {
                GetAddPage(linkCode);
                
            }
        }
    });
});

// Mock function for GetAddPage
function GetAddPage(linkCode) {
    alert('Link code: ' + linkCode);
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dynamic Menu Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="MainMenu"></ul>
</body>
</html>




thank you very much for your replay . your code is more clear and better than my code and i am going to us it . but that is not the problem  the problem is the drop list it self do not toggle or drop down when i add it dynamically  (class="my-main-menu") . and since its working when its static fine and not working when i add it dynamically . the issue is on the method i use to add it. and i see you used the same method i used document.getElementById("MainMenu").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", MenuAllContent);

Sorry I missunderstood your problem... in that scenario Iam not sure how to go around that problem
